# Custom function for specific user role

Tags: functions, user-roles

I need to run some functions/filters for specific user roles.
This code filters the admin order page (Woocommerce) to only show orders that are in GBP.

```
add_filter('request', function($vars) {
global $typenow, $wpdb;

// Add logic to determine if the orders list should be filtered, and which
// currency
$currency = 'GBP';

if($typenow == 'shop_order') {
$vars['meta_query']['relation'] = 'AND';
// Only show orders in the specific currency
$vars['meta_query'] = array(
    array(
        'key' => '_order_currency',
        'value' => $currency,
        'compare' => '=',
        ),
    );
}
return $vars;
}, 15 );
```

This works as expected.
What I need to do is make this code only run for certain roles.
The role I need to fire it on is `uk_staff`.
I then need to create the same thing except for `$currency = 'AUD';` and the role `au_staff`.

Can anyone give me some help making this function only fire for certain roles?

Comment: You should ask inside your custom function for the role, [`if ( ! current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) return; `](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_user_can).

Comment: @bueltge I'm not sure how to tie that in with the other if statement,  can I simply add it before the other if statement?

Comment: You should add my example after the `global` statement, to that if the user have not (`!`) the role, exit/return of the request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The core has functions like [`current_user_can`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_user_can) to check for an capability of a role or check the role directly. The follow example extend your source for this check so that the function not (`!`) run, if the current user haven't the rights, the capability of his role.

```
add_filter('request', function( $vars ) {

// Check the capability of the current user.
if ( ! current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) )
    return;

global $typenow, $wpdb;

// Add logic to determine if the orders list should be filtered, and which
// currency
$currency = 'GBP';

if($typenow == 'shop_order') {
$vars['meta_query']['relation'] = 'AND';
// Only show orders in the specific currency
$vars['meta_query'] = array(
    array(
        'key'     => '_order_currency',
        'value'   => $currency,
        'compare' => '=',
        ),
    );
}
return $vars;
}, 15 );
```

Comment: Thanks for this. When I try and implement on it's on its own it works as expected. When I try and add another condition it just shows blank, can you check this gist and let me know what I am doing wrong? https://gist.github.com/webthread/9fd801090f1864185e1485b9ec90e56c

Comment: Active the WP_DEBUG mode so that you get an error message. This should helps you. Also, you should create a function, there you use only once, with different values for the rights. Currently you run redundant dynamically the same logic, only different capability to check.